# Meteor: issue using alanning:roles with patch installed (upgrading project from v0.9.3.1 to v1.2.0.1)

Tags: meteor

I've just installed [this patch](https://github.com/challett/meteor-roles/tree/patch-3) for the [alanning:roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) package and I'm now getting these errors:

```
WARNING: Roles template helpers not registered. Handlebars or UI package not found

lookup.js:186 Uncaught Error: No such function: isInRole
```

This is the code the produces the first error:

```
if (Package.ui) {
  _.each(Roles._uiHelpers, function (func, name) {
    Package.ui.UI.registerHelper(name, func) 
  })
} else if (Package.handlebars) {
  _.each(Roles._uiHelpers, function (func, name) {
    Package.handlebars.Handlebars.registerHelper(name, func)
  })
} else {
  console.log && console.log('WARNING: Roles template helpers not registered. Handlebars or UI package not found')
}
```

Anyone know what I need do to sort these issues?  Looks like this has come up before: [link](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/issues/28)

this is my `meteor list` output:

```
accounts-password                  1.1.3  Password support for accounts
accounts-ui                        1.1.6  Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
alanning:roles                     1.2.13+ Authorization package for Meteor
aldeed:autoform                    5.5.1  Easily create forms with automatic insert and update, and automatic reactive...
aldeed:collection2                 2.5.0  Automatic validation of insert and update operations on the client and server.
aldeed:simple-schema               1.3.3  A simple schema validation object with reactivity. Used by collection2 and a...
blaze-html-templates               1.0.1  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor Blaze
cfs:filesystem                     0.1.2  Filesystem storage adapter for CollectionFS
cfs:standard-packages              0.5.9  Filesystem for Meteor, collectionFS
ecmascript                         0.1.4  Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
ejson                              1.0.7  Extended and Extensible JSON library
es5-shim                           4.1.13  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
insecure                           1.0.4  (For prototyping only) Allow all database writes from the client
iron:router                        1.0.9  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
jquery                             1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
matb33:collection-hooks            0.8.0  Extends Mongo.Collection with before/after hooks for insert/update/remove/fi...
meteor-base                        1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs
meteorhacks:npm                    1.5.0  Use npm modules with your Meteor App
mobile-experience                  1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                              1.1.1  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
mrt:accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3  0.2.7  A roles based account management system using bootstrap 3
mrt:jquery-jcrop                   0.0.3  jQuery Jcrop repackaged for Meteor
mrt:loading                        0.0.1  Loading overlay + spinner
npm-container                      1.2.0+ Contains all your npm dependencies
random                             1.0.4  Random number generator and utilities
session                            1.1.1  Session variable
spacebars                          1.0.7  Handlebars-like template language for Meteor
standard-minifiers                 1.0.0  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker                            1.0.8  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
twbs:bootstrap                     3.3.5  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first...
```

Comment: sure I'll give that a go cheers :) .... I've added my meteor list to the original post

Comment: That seemed to fix it :) ..... and ta da my project appears on the page .... wonder what else needs fixed ;)

Comment: @challett Since your comments are now integrated in your answer I suggest deleting them to clean the question. You may want to add a link to your fork/PR in your answer to preserve this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package needed to have `blaze-html-templates` listed as a weak dependency along with `handlebars`.  Meteor 1.2 removed a lot of packages from the core that were installed by default.

The patch has been updated to reflect these changes.

```
api.use(['blaze-html-templates', 'handlebars'], 'client', {weak: true});
```

**Instead of**

```
api.use(['handlebars'], 'client', {weak: true});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with that.  That's been a major help to me!

Comment: No problem, the patch was merged into the package recently so you should now be able to move back to the official package